# Jitpack with Gitlab public repository gives No read access to repo error

Tags: android, gitlab, android-library, jitpack

I can't seem to figure out how to publish my Android library to Jitpack using a public Gitlab repo. I've followed every tutorial and stack overflow example I could find, but nothing seems to work.

My public repo is here https://gitlab.com/onetapaway-opensource/kotlin/sumotree

Jitpack just gives me `No read access to repo` error as seen here
https://jitpack.io/#com.gitlab.onetapaway-opensource.kotlin/sumotree

Comment: https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/#gitlab

Comment: @djames I saw that, but I'm not using a private gitlab repo.

Comment: Can confirm that, I have the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't had a chance to dig in on this again. I'm still just copy/pasting between 2 projects at the moment. Luckily, the code that I share doesn't change very often. If you figure it out please share here. Otherwise, I'll get back to it at some point.